Run service on application shutting down ASP.NET Core
I need to implement logic that executes before an ASP.NET Core application shuts down. Is there a built-in solution for tracking application shutdown events?
While I can add the logic after calling app.Run();, it would be more convenient if there were a service, such as a BackgroundService registered with AddHostedService, that runs at startup and integrates with the DI container.
Thank you!

You can have 2 processes run, one can start another and use memory mapped files to communicate the end of the process
in the Program/Startup when calling your app's .Run()
var file = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew("file id", 1, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite);
var view = file.CreateViewAccessor();
view.Write(0, true); // <-- change this value when Run() is exiting 

// here start your other process

in another process
var file = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("file id", MemoryMappedFileRights.FullControl);
var _view = file.CreateViewAccessor();

// periodically run this on timer or something
bool running = _view.ReadBoolean(0);
if (!running)
{
    // do something, exit
}

You could also use Mutex, gRPC...
